# onItemSelected won't get called

Tags: android, spinner

Implementing the basic spinner example from the android website won't call call the onItemSelected. I haven't found a solution after reading around 25 answers in StackOverflow. 
I can see the options on the spinner, but when I select one nothing happens. here is the code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner)

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this,
        R.array.sources,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    ).also { adapter ->
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.adapter = adapter
    }

    class SpinnerActivity : Activity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {

            Log.d("nothing", "happending")

            when (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()){
                "file 1" -> Log.d("Selection","file 1")
                "file 2" -> Log.d("selection", "file 2")
                else -> text.append("No match")
            }

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Called made",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            // Another interface callback
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Get rid of the `SpinnerActivity` inner class, and move all of the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` stuff to `MainActivity`. You would then set the listener like `spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it works perfectly. Could you please tell me what "this" means for onItemSelectedListener ? Are we giving some type of View to it ? if so, which one ? Thanks man.

Comment: `this` refers to the current object; in this case, the current `MainActivity` instance. It's implementing the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` interface, so that's what we set as the listener. You don't have to do it like that. It was just the option that I thought would be the clearest to describe. You could certainly do it like Rafael shows below. It's functionally the same; that just has a separate object that implements the interface, instead of having `MainActivity` do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the inner class SpinnerActivity, you should register the listener on the spinner:

```
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {

            Log.d("nothing", "happending")

            when (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()){
                "file 1" -> Log.d("Selection","file 1")
                "file 2" -> Log.d("selection", "file 2")
                else -> text.append("No match")
            }

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Called made",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            // Another interface callback
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I implemented this at the end. sorry, cant give an upvote, because of lack of rep 

Comment: @Rick.O, Mike solution also works well. I'd use Mike's solution when I have multiple views of the same type (e.g. button) which generally uses the same code. in those cases, better to do it once than creating code duplication and creating a boilerplate for handling those views.